# Превью изображений перед отправкой формы

Tags: jquery, изображения, javascript

Добрый вечер, друзья.

Мне нужно было сделать превью изображений перед отправкой формы, но я очень слаб в js. =( По этому сделал такие костыли:

```
<div>
    <img id="image_preview" class="thumb"/>
    <input type="file" class="image" id="image_preview" />
</div>

<div>
    <img id="image_preview2" class="thumb"/>
    <input type="file" class="image" id="image_preview2" />
</div>

и т.д., может быть сколько угодно input'ов

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.image').change(function() {
  var input = $(this)[0];
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
    if ( input.files[0].type.match('image.*') ) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) { $('#'+id).attr('src', e.target.result); }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Но мне как-то совсем не нравится, может, кто сможет подсказать, как сделать более красиво и правильно? Возможно ли как-то избавится от `id="image_preview"` в инпутах и имэйджах? И также подскажите, пожалуйста, должен ли этот вариант работать во всех браузерах? Проверил в современных IE, Chrome, FireFox - везде работает.

Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Разумеется, код я нагуглил, добавив только свои костыли - `id="image_preview"` и `$('#'+id).attr('src', e.target.result)`.

Comment: Этот вариант не будет работать в IE9 и ниже: в них нет еще FileReader API

Comment: А для них что то можно по быстрому сделать?
Как они утомили... верстка, js, чтож сложного обновится, сейчас глянул метрику, таких 4%.

Comment: К сожалению, я лично не нашел чисто клиентского решения для данной проблемы. В одном из проектов, где я столкнулся с этим, я реализовал все через сервер, но там я имел дело с одной картинкой, а у тут их могут быть десятки, поэтому  боюсь, что мое решение не подойдет.

Comment: А как то можно избавится от id="image_preview"
Т.е. сделать просто:
<div>
    <img class="thumb"/>
    <input type="file" class="image" />
</div>
Не знаю как сослаться на img в таком случаи вот тут: reader.onload = function(e) { $('#'+id).attr('src', e.target.result); }

Пробую так: reader.onload = function(e) { $(this).parent('div').find('img').attr('src', e.target.result); } - не получается :(

Comment: @Deimos_ru, я не очень понимаю, что именно вас смущает в вашем коде, но могу предложить [такой вариант][1] (*можно выбирать сразу несколько фото*). 

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/s0zseema/

Comment: @Deonis, чуть лучше - https://jsfiddle.net/s0zseema/1/ :)

Comment: @TheDoctor, не помешает. Но и атрибут "accept", как всё разбираемое тут, так же затрагивает вопрос кроссбраузерность.

Comment: @Deonis, есть такое.  
Но если задумано заюзать `API FileReader`, то и атрибут, скорее всего, поддерживается.  
Открыл папку, 100500 разных файлов, пока картинку нашёл - запарился, вот и вставил, да и кошерно это.

Comment: `var input = $(this)[0];` - это же `var input = this;`

Comment: [Вот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh580307(v=vs.85).aspx) занимательная литература, а [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/s0zseema/5/) подправленный скрипт.